# Interest of having two functions doing the exact same thing

Tags: functions, r

`ls` and `objects` functions are both from the `base` package and are exactly the same as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602761/difference-between-ls-and-objects). I've seen other examples of duplicated functions (in the `tidyverse` and `base` if I remember correctly). To me, having this type of functions juste make the code less clear by introducing more and more functions.

I don't see neither the interest of having duplicated functions in different packages (as we can load packages B, C, D while loading package A).

What is the point of having duplicated functions? Is this type of functions just a remain from the past due to the long existence of an open source language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there are four common reasons why:

- Historical / Legacy

  - They may have come from different places, or been different once upon a time and slowly became the same.
- Lack of Knowledge / Misunderstanding

  - They may have been created by different people and are accidentally the same. Maybe they were created, under a false assumption about the other one.
- Personal Taste

  - The developer just wanted it called a different thing that is more intuitive for them.
- Further Control

  - The code may be the same now, but that may not always be true. Perhaps a developer feels they have the right to change one of the functions, or at least wants to reserve the right to do so.